# copy file with destination permission

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, cp

we use “cp” command to copy files from one location to another. Then, we use “chmod”, and “chown” commands to change the permissions and ownership of a file, respectively. However, we can combine all these tasks into a single one-liner command, and still get the same result instead of running the three consecutive commands. This can be helpful when you want to do this on a regular basis, or within a script. i want this script because i want to 1 file in many folder with destination permission?

Answer (score 3):

use **--no-preserve** to preserve the destination mode/ownership

```
cp --no-preserve=mode,ownership source_file destination_file
```